# Webfont alternative to Segoe UI

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Need to find a replacement for Microsoft fonts for a 'metro-style' UI design project. Just wondering what the best replacement might be because of Segoe's evolution from Fruitger.

In terms of a suitable font replacement, I would have thought that the main criteria is for the font family to have styles in different weights (Light, Regular, Semibold, Bold, Extra bold, etc), and that the general look and feel is similar enough and would fit with a interaction (and tile) based visual styling.

I thought about something like Clear Sans or Open Sans, but what are people's experiences with them?

A list of possible alternatives (in no particular order):

- Open Sans
- Clear Sans
- Droid Sans
- Noto

Comment: Here's a metric-compatible alternative from Microsoft themselves: https://github.com/Microsoft/Selawik

Answer (score 6):

I personally love Open Sans. I've used it for a number of different projects and found it great to work with. Glyph and language support is exceptional, readability is great even at small sizes, and I could go on.

Be advised that Google recently changed the name to [Noto](https://code.google.com/p/noto/) for some reason.

[Webly Sleek](http://www.fonts2u.com/weblysleek-ui-semibold.font) is also very similar to Segoe, and has good glyph support.

[image]

Comment: Noto is actually a variation of Droid Sans, so it's more of a cousin than a renamed version.

Comment: Oh, I was told it was just a rename... Anyways, both are still around, so OP can take his pick.

Comment: Why do you think Webly Sleek is similar to Segoe? I found the look and feel quite different.

Comment: I added an image comparing the two. Except for the Q, I don't see ant major differences?

Comment: Perhaps I should take that comment back, but I am sure there would be other differences for other upper case characters and also the numbers between the two fonts? Otherwise it would be almost an exact copy?

Comment: There are differences, of course. But the OP asked for a 'suitable replacement', not an exact copy. Imho, Webly Sleek will make no difference to Segoe from a UX point of view.

Comment: Look at the uppercase i in Segoe, Open Sans and Noto. Noto's uppercase i has serif.